# Minimize and Table of variables

Tags: mathematical-optimization, system-variables

I use a list of variables to **Minimize** a particular quantity

```
{ Q, val1, Table[Pi, {i, 1, m, 1}}
```

where **i** is the subscript of P. However in this way I have

```
{ Q, val1, {P1, P2.. Pm}}
```

that does not work (it is necessary a list of variables).

This is my code, I have to minimize the total cost of the supply chain. 
For exemple for m=1 the P (production rate) that determinate the minimum cost should be 300:

```
Remove["Global`*"];
Av = 10;
Ab = 4;
b = 0.0001;
beta = 1;
Cv = 0.01;
Cb = 0.1;
Edom = 100;
g = 8;
hv = 0.0025;
hb = 0.004;
Z = 5;
alfa = 2;
delta = 5;
gamma = 1;
dev = 20;
w0 = 30;
k = 0.01;
e = 0.1;
ton = 0.1;
o = 0.1;
Ar = 2;
ctotfin = 100000000000000;
ctotparz = 100000000000000;

m = 0;
While[ctotparz <= ctotfin,
m++;
x = NMinimize[{(Av*Edom)/Round[Q] + (m*Ar*Edom)/
  Round[Q] + ((m*(m - 1))/Edom + 1/Subscript[P, 1] - 
     Sum[(Sum[1/Subscript[P, j], {j, 2, i - 1}] + 
        Sum[1/Subscript[P, j], {j, 2, i}]), {i, 2, m}])*(
   Edom*hv*Round[Q])/(2*m^2) + 
  Edom/m*(Sum[(g/Subscript[P, i] + 
       b*(Subscript[P, i])^beta + (w0/Subscript[P, i] + k)*
        e), {i, 1, m}]) + (w0 + 
     Max[Table[Subscript[P, i], {i, 1, m, 1}]]*k)*o + 
  alfa*Edom*Cv + Edom/Round[Q]*(m*Ab + m*Z) + 
  Cb*Edom + (Round[Q]/(2*m) + 
     val1*dev*Sqrt[Round[Q]/(m*Subscript[P, 1]) + delta + ton])*
   hb + (gamma*Edom*dev)/
   Round[Q]*(Sqrt[

      Round[Q]/(m*Subscript[P, 1]) + delta + 
       ton]*(PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], val1] - 
        val1*(1 - CDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], val1])) + (m - 1)*
      Sqrt[delta]*(PDF[
         NormalDistribution[0, 
          1], (val1*Sqrt[
           Round[Q]/(m*Subscript[P, 1]*delta) + ton/delta + 
            1])] - (val1*Sqrt[
           Round[Q]/(m*Subscript[P, 1]*delta) + ton/delta + 
            1])*(1 - 
           CDF[NormalDistribution[0, 
             1], (val1*Sqrt[
              Round[Q]/(m*Subscript[P, 1]*delta) + ton/delta + 
               1])]))),  
Round[Q] > 0   && Table[Subscript[P, i], {i, 1, m, 1}] >= 101 && 
  Table[Subscript[P, i], {i, 1, m, 1}] <= 300 && 
  Table[Subscript[P, i], {i, 1, m, 1}] ∈ 
   Integers && (1 - 
     CDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 
      val1] + (m - 1)*(1 - 
        CDF[NormalDistribution[0, 
          1], (val1*Sqrt[
           Round[Q]/(m*Subscript[P, 1]*delta) + ton/delta + 
            1])])) == (hb*Round[Q])/(gamma*Edom) }, 
Flatten[{ Table[Subscript[P, i], {i, 1, m, 1}], Round[Q], val1}]];
ctotparz = x[[1]];
y = x[[2]];
Pparz = Table[Subscript[P, i], {i, 1, m, 1}] /. y[[1 ;; m]];
Qparz = Round[Round[Q] /. y[[m + 1]]];
val1parz = val1 /. y[[m + 2]];
If[ctotparz <= ctotfin, ( ctotfin = ctotparz;  Qfin = Qparz;  
Pfin = Pparz), ctotparz = ctotparz]];
mfin = m - 1; 
Print[ctotfin];
Print[Qfin] ;
Print[Pfin];
Print[mfin]
```

Comment: The code you posted, does not evaluate to the result you posted. Please edit and fix the syntax error and other problems. e.g. `Pi` is the symbol for the mathematical constant Pi

Comment: I didn't write the symbol for the mathematical constant Pi, as I said also in the post **i** is the subscript of P. `{ Q, val1, {P1, P2.. Pm}}` is how the programm see my list of variables, and it returns this error: ` Variables { Q, val1, {P1, P2.. Pm}} should be a list of variables`.  I think that is for the double brackets.

Comment: Maybe `Flatten[{Q, val1, {P1, P2, P3}}]`? Gives `{Q, val1, P1, P2, P3}`.

Comment: It works!! thankyou!! I have an other question, I put in **Minimize** this constriaint  `Element[Table[Pi, {i, 1, m, 1}], Integers]` but this cause an elimination of some integers that actually determinate the minimum of my function! How is it possible?

Comment: Use an [`indexed variable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/MakingDefinitionsForIndexedObjects.html) rather than a [`Subscript`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Subscript.html). If you want `P[i]` displayed as a `Subscript` use [`Format`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Format.html), e.g., evaluate `Format[P[i_]] := Subscript[P, i]; pVar = Array[P, 3]` This will make the code that you post here something that will evaluate after being copied and pasted into a notebook.

Comment: Hard to tell why some integers were eliminated without knowing what the function is. Can you please edit your post and add the definition of the function you are trying to minimize.

Comment: Thanks, ok I add my model to the post. I had the same problem with Q and i solved using Round  @Rohit Namjoshi